# How to Setup GitLens in VS Code for a Local Server?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, repository, lan

I want to share my project in Visual Studio Code on our local server `192.168.1.200` for example, using a plugin like GitLens, but I can not find a way to do so without sharing that project globally on GitHub!.

I installed the plugin, and in the `settings.json` file:

```
{
    "gitlens.remotes": [{ "domain": "192.168.1.200/subDir..", "type": "GitLens" }] 
}
```

But there is error under type `GitLens` says:

`Value is not accepted. Valid values: "Bitbucket", "BitbucketServer", "Custom", "GitHub", "GitLab".(1)`

This configuration seems to be for the VSCode itself and not related to Gitlens, is this the correct way to start?

What is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
"type": "GitHub"
```

for my Gitea, but recently found that Gitea is already supported in the VS Code
[All supported types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE9Ef.png)

Comment: Is `Gitea` a typo for `GitLens`?

Comment: It is not a typo. Use "GitHub" if your type is not in the supported list